# PDO register user function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So after hours and hours of debugging, I cannot find a way to get my code to work. If anyone could help me or point me in the right direction that would be much appreciated. Also, how do I go about keeping this part of my code secure?

```
if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {
                $register_data = array(
                    'username' => $_POST['username'],
                    'password' => $_POST['password'],
                    'email' => $_POST['email'],
                    'email_code' => md5($_POST['username'] + microtime())
                );
                register_user($db, $register_data);
                header('location: register.php?success');
                exit();
            }
```

Then is the `register_user` function

```
function register_user(PDO $db, $register_data) {
    array_walk($register_data, 'array_sanitize');
    $register_datapw = $register_data['password'];
    require ('blowfish.class.php');
    $bcrypt = new Bcrypt(4);
    $register_datapw = $bcrypt->hash($register_datapw);

    $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($register_data)) . '`';
    $data = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $register_data) . '\'';

    $query = "INSERT INTO `users` ($fields) VALUES ($data)";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();   
}
```

Errors~
`Argument 1 passed to register_user() must be an instance of PDO, array given, called in...`

I feel like I've dug myself into a hole that I can't find the way out of, literally my brain is fried but I've managed to get all the way through my error reporting and debugging that until I've finally reached the pinnacle and I'm stumped!

EDIT:

I've done as you've said and I believe it's worked, but now I'm faced with this.
`mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established`

```
function array_sanitize(&$item){
$item = htmlentities(strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($item)));
}
```

Comment: Where is `$db` defined? It's evidently an array, not a PDO instance.

Comment: `$db = new PDO("mysql:host=".$config['db']['host'].";dbname=".$config['db']['dbname'], $config['db']['username'], $config['db']['password']);` in my connect.php which is included

Comment: I'd be checking your code between there and the snippet you posted above, as it appears to be getting overwritten at some point. `var_dump($db)` immediately before your call to `register_user()` may give you an indication of where to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using a PDO prepare method; try NOT to pass your values to the query as string and instead bind them or provide them at runtime:

```
$fields = '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($register_data)) . '`';
$data = ':' . implode(', :', array_keys($register_data)) . '';

$query = "INSERT INTO `users` ($fields) VALUES ($data)";
stmt = $db->prepare( $query );
$stmt->execute( $register_data );
```

Comment: I've done as you've said and I believe it's worked, but now there's a problem with my array_santize.. I've updated my question with the error I'm getting.

Comment: With PDO implementation; you can not access mysql_* functions. Also; you absolutely don't need them as PDO will take care of sanitization itself @user2305310

Comment: @user2305310 Short answer: Just remove the array-walk statement from code. You **DO NOT** need it at all.

Comment: It would appear that was the correct way of doing it :) thank you again.